# ORA-04020 on Oracle SE1 (11.2.0.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, deadlock

We've been experiencing some deadlock issues on our Oracle SE1 (11.2.0.1) database server (Red Hat 5/64bit)

Seeing ORA-04020 errors in the logs.

Is going to 11.2.0.2 the only way to resolve the deadlock issue?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Simon,

it would be worth looking at the following

- are there any invalid objects in the database; if so recompile
- have you got [this situation](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=250396) if so packaged procedures are the way to go.
- have you got user managed locking going on, if so maybe reconsider?